# Object refers to different memory address after adding redis-session-sharing function in spring

Tags: java, spring, session, redis

I'm trying to add [spring-session with redis using xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/samples/xml/redis) to an existing spring 3 project.

However, I found that the session object, which is get by using 
`user = (User)session.getAttribute(USER_ID);`, becomes different objects after adding spring-session with redis.

I mean before I add redis spring-session function, the debug log is:

```
[DEBUG] user object when first created: com.company.User@63e02404
[DEBUG] user object before something goes wrong: com.company.User@63e02404
```

Notice that the above two users refer to the same memory. This means that they belong to the same instance.

After adding redis spring-session function the debug log becomes:

```
[DEBUG] user object when first created: com.company.User@bf98354
[DEBUG] user object before something goes wrong: com.company.User@711d0e44
```

The two user objects don't refer to the same memory address anymore. This creates some bugs to the project. For example, `user.getName()` returns an empty string, `""`, after adding spring-session.

The code related to spring-session is as the following:

`WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

`WEB-INF/context.xml`:

```
<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="127.0.0.1" />
    <property name="port" value="6379" />
</bean>
<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.StringRedisTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<util:constant static-field="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP"/>

<!-- Session -->
<bean id="redisHttpSessionConfiguration"  class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration" >
    <property name="maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds" value="120" />
</bean>
```

`User.java`

```
public class User extends JdkSerializationRedisSerializer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

What might cause this problem?

I've checked that redis contains `user`'s data.

Sorry that I haven't figured out a way to create a minimal environment for reproducing this phenomenon.

If you need any other information about the project, just tell me. I'll paste that information to the question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this setup but I'd guess that the object is sent to Redis upon creation/changes and read back in the interceptor. That of course would create a new instance of that object to be created and that would naturally have a different memory address. In general when using such caching techniques you shouldn't keep references to the objects but do lookups to the cache and if you put those objects into sets or use them as map keys they should have a correct implementation of `hashCode()` and `equals()`

Comment: Ofcourse they will be different object instances as they get serialized and deserialized. Also the behavior shouldn't change, regardless of the fact that it is the same instance or not.

Comment: @M.Deinum. If this is something normal, then I think I have to look for other clues about the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original spring 3 project didn't add `user` back to session after it is initialized.

```
public String processManagement(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  User user = (User)request.getSession().getAttribute(User.USER_ID);
  managementService.initRequiredInfo(request, user);
  ...
```

After adding `request.getSession().setAttribute(User.USER_SID, user);` to the above code. The bug doesn't occur anymore.

```
public String processManagement(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  User user = (User)request.getSession().getAttribute(User.USER_ID);
  managementService.initRequiredInfo(request, user);
  request.getSession().setAttribute(User.USER_SID, user);
  ...
```